# TextureRegion.split Android studio error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this error: "Cannot Resolve symbol 'split' " for line

```
    rollSpriteSheet = new  TextureRegion.split(new Texture("ship.png"),Constants.SHIP_WIDTH_PIXEL,Constants.SHIP_HEIGHT_PIXEL);
```

I have declared TextureRegion too and in Message Gradle Build I'm getting:

```
Error:(35, 45) error: cannot find symbol class split
```

This is my code:

```
public class ShapexScreen extends InputAdapter implements Screen {
    public static final String TAG = ShapexScreen.class.getName();
    float x;
    float y;
    Animation[] rolls;
    TextureRegion[][] rollSpriteSheet;
    int roll;
    float stateTime; //statetime is adding delta time every frame
    Foflex game;

    public ShapexScreen(Foflex game){
        this.game = game;
        y = 15;
        x = Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH /2 - Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH /2;
        roll = 2; //roll 2 would be in middle
        rolls = new Animation[5]; //Five different roll states
        rollSpriteSheet = new  TextureRegion.split(new Texture("ship.png"),Constants.SHIP_WIDTH_PIXEL,Constants.SHIP_HEIGHT_PIXEL); //2d array to store the ship sprite sheet
        rolls[roll] = new Animation(Constants.ANIMATION_SPEED, rollSpriteSheet[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`TextureRegion`**](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html)

> Defines a rectangular area of a texture. The coordinate system used
>   has its origin in the upper left corner with the x-axis pointing to
>   the right and the y axis pointing downwards.

```
Error:(35, 45) error: cannot find symbol class split
```

You should call this way

```
rollSpriteSheet = TextureRegion.split(new Texture("ship.png"),Constants.SHIP_WIDTH_PIXEL,Constants.SHIP_HEIGHT_PIXEL);
```

**FYI**

```
public TextureRegion[][] split(int tileWidth,
                                int tileHeight)
```

> Helper function to create tiles out of this TextureRegion starting
>   from the top left corner going to the right and ending at the bottom
>   right corner. Only complete tiles will be returned so if the region's
>   width or height are not a multiple of the tile width and height not
>   all of the region will be used. This will not work on texture regions
>   returned form a TextureAtlas that either have whitespace removed or
>   where flipped before the region is split.

Comment: It helped. Thank you.